# Search for user by Username in AWS Cognito

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to find a user by searching with a `Username` in AWS Lambda? The `GetUserCommand` does not seem to accept a `Username` as a parameter. The [input shape](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/interfaces/cognitoidentityproviderclientresolvedconfig.html) does not include a Username parameter. Am I misunderstanding?

[GetUserCommand documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/classes/getusercommand.html).

Answer (score 0):

The command you are referring to only needs an access token. Since the access token belongs to your user it will return information about her/him. You don't really need to provide a username. Would be kind of redundant.

If you want to get information about a user as an admin (so not as a user that is currently signed in), then you need another method: [AdminGetUserCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/classes/admingetusercommand.html). There you can specify which username you want using [AdminGetUserCommandInput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/interfaces/admingetusercommandinput.html).